# How download files of folder in a web server?

Tags: android, download

I now have an app with Andoid, and I want to download files onto my sdcard. The files are in a folder and there might be a folder in the folder.

How do I download the whole folder from a web server to my sdcard?

I have edited the manifest.xml in my project and know how to download a file to my sdcard, but how do I download an entire folder without changing the structure.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could:

Zip the folder, download the zip, and unzip.

Produce a list of files on the web server (`ls -1 > ls.txt`), and use that as an index to tell you which files to download.